# Analysing "So amazed he cannot speak"

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

In the sentence: "So amazed he cannot speak", is "amazed" an adjective?

Comment: this isn't a full sentence.  it's a fragment.  it lacks a verb (likely "to be" as in "He was so amazed...").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **X** has to be an adjective in the predicate construction

- *be so **X** that **S***

where **S** is any tensed clause (in this case, **S** = *he cannot speak*).

If it were a noun phrase, one would use *such (a)* instead of *so*

- *be such (a(n)) **X** that **S***

E.g,

- *He was **so mean** that she slapped him.*
- *He was **such a jerk** that she slapped him.*

Both of these mean that the degree of **X** is high enough to bring about **S**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `amazed` is an adjective. It describes `he`.

**Edit:**

Per the comments, if the sentence was expanded to `He was so amazed...` the word `amazed` would be a predicate adjective describing `he`.