# Is using "too" correct in "As X, so too Y"?

Tags: sentence, comparisons

Is the usage of "too" correct in this sentence?

> As the systems we simulate become increasingly complex, so too does the task of validation.

Comment: Have you looked up the word _too_ in a dictionary?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: Come to think of think, why not omit the word "too" altogether. I kind of like the sound of, "As the systems we simulate become increasingly complex, so does the task of validation."

Comment: I asked a similar question about a year ago here: [Function of “too” in the phrase “so too” or “so, too”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/function-of-too-in-the-phrase-so-too-or-so-too). The answers are pretty interesting, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of *too* is fine. An alternate word to use instead of *too* would be the synonym *also*.

Occasionally, depending on the wording of the sentence, the word *too* is preceded and followed by a comma, but commas are not necessary in your sentence. In the following sentences, however, the commas would be appropriate, though not necessary:

> - We think Jack should come along with us, too.
> - We think Jack should come along with us, too, but his mother disagrees.
> - Jack's father and older brother, too, are in agreement with his mother.
> - As the systems we simulate become increasingly complex, the task of validation becomes increasingly complex, too.

Come to think of it, why not omit the word *too* altogether. I kind of like the sound of,

> "As the systems we simulate become increasingly complex, so does the task of validation."

Comment: I like the comma where the OP has it. It makes the sentence easier to read, and it's not there because of the "too".

Comment: @Rupe: I agree. I realize the comma is there because the sentence needs it for ease of reading, not because of the OP's use of the word "too." The same would apply in a compound sentence, such as, "The systems we simulate become increasingly complex, and so too does the task of validation."

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bringing commas into this? it seems to me that the question is about the meaning or function of the word _too_.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: Bringing commas into this doesn't seem unreasonable to me. I personally think the comma before ***too*** in rhetorician's second and third examples looks really weird, to say the least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You could be right. The way I speak the sentences, though, sounds better to me with the comma-pauses. Then again, I tend to speak more slowly than the average person. A faster-speaking person would not likely feel the need for commas. Don

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: Because of your comment, I've edited my answer by including some more information; notice the second sentence in the first paragraph, and my addition of the words "though not necessary," thanks to FumbleFingers. Don

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer *as well* at the end of the sentence instead of *too*.