# Identifying parts of a sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses, conjunction-reduction

How do the bolded sections of the sentences below function grammatically? (taken from David McCullough's *John Adams*)

1. Philadelphia, the provincial capital of Pennsylvania on the western bank of the Delaware River, was a true eighteenth-century metropolis, the largest, wealthiest city in British America, **and the most beautiful.**

   > It seems to me that "most beautiful" could be tacked onto the the string of adjectives ( the "largest, wealthiest") that precede it. Is there a name for this sort of construction, wherein the last item in a string of modifiers is pulled out and moved to the end?
2. Distilleries and breweries were thriving. Adams found the local beer **so much to his liking** that he temporarily abandoned his usual hard cider.

   > I'm not sure what's modifying what here. I see the main clause, "Adams found the local beer," and the subordinate clause, "that he temporarily abandoned his usual hard cider," but what's going on the middle?

Comment: You can't just glibly say *Adams found the local beer* is a "main clause". In this specific context ***found*** is equivalent to, say, ***thought, considered, judged***, so without the adjectival component *so much to his liking* it's not really a "clause" at all. Structurally the example is the same as *He thought the beer insipid*, where it doesn't make a lot of sense to say *He thought the beer* is a clause.

Comment: I see that now; I'm new to grammar myself, but does this at all relate to the distinction between transitive and intransitive verbs?

Comment: I don't think *transitive/intransitive* is relevant here. The verb ***find*** is always transitive (you can't just say *He found*). The point is it can be used with different meanings - so it's valid to say *I hid the beer, but he found it*, but it's also valid to say *I liked the beer, but he found it unpalatable*. And your example reflect the second of those two, in which context the adjectival component (my *unpalatable*, your *so much to his liking*) is an integral part of the clause within which it's contained.

Answer (score 3):

> Philadelphia...was a true eighteenth-century metropolis, **the largest, wealthiest city in British America**, and the most beautiful.

The phrase *the largest, wealthiest city in British America* is a noun group (a noun plus modifiers), and it functions as an apposition to the noun group *a true eighteenth-century metropolis* (it indirectly modifies it, as a kind of afterthought; it gives an additional description).

The phrase *and the most beautiful* is best considered elliptical: it stands for a longer phrase of which some parts are omitted. The longer phrase would be as follows:

> Philadelphia...was a true eighteenth-century metropolis, the largest, wealthiest city in British America, **and the most beautiful [city in British America]**.

So it is the short form of a longer phrase that functions as a second apposition to *a true eighteenth-century metropolis*.

---

> Distilleries and breweries were thriving. Adams found the local beer **so much to his liking *that he temporarily abandoned his usual hard cider***.

The verb *find* can be used with three complements: a subject (*Adams*), a direct object (*the local beer*), and an object complement (*so much to his liking that he temporarily abandoned his usual hard cider*). There are quite a few verbs that can have object complements, e.g. *she painted the house green, I thought him quaint, I made the box larger*. Object complements are somewhat similar to subject complements, in that they usually ascribe a property to or identity with the object: *I found him stupid* is similar to *I found that he was stupid*.

The subordinate clause *that...* is dependent on / modifies the pronominal adverb *so*: the word *so* expresses that it was to his liking to a certain degree (adverbial function), and it signals that the degree should be or will soon be known to the reader (pronominal function). When I say *the wall was so tall*, I might be using my hand to indicate *how* tall. So the word *so* refers to the degree or manner indicated by my hand. In your case, the degree is made clear in the subordinate clause *that*. It is very common to connect *so* with a *that* clause like this.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out irrelevant details, the example sentences are

> 1. *Philadelphia was the largest, wealthiest city in British America, and the most beautiful*.
> 2. *Adams found the beer so much to his liking that he temporarily abandoned  hard cider.*

Both of these are picturesque comparisons, gauded up with a lot of syntax.

(1) is a superlative construction, with three superlative adjective forms:

- *the largest,*
- *wealthiest,* and
- *the most beautiful*

The first two are put together in apposition under one *the*, while the phrasal superlative gets a special place at the end, with the noun phrase it modifies deleted by [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299).

- *It was the largest, wealthiest city, and (it was) the most beautiful (city)*

So the answer to the first question is that it's an adjective phrase that's been stranded for emphasis.

(2) is an equative (actually a comparative -- he prefers one over the other, but you hafta figure that out from the text; it's not in the grammar) using [the *so/such .. that `S`* construction.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/119601/15299)

*So* is used before adjective and adverb phrases,

- *so hot a day that `S`, he laughs so strangely that `S`*,

and *such* before noun phrases

- *such a hot day that `S`, such a strange laugh that `S`*

to indicate (in a *that* clause `S`) the degree  of some scalable property (like heat or strangeness).

The idiom *to find `X` (to be) to one's liking* means 'to discover that one likes `X`'.
The *so much .. that* part refers to the degree of that liking, to be gauged from the clause following.